# OpenGL - How to draw to a multisample framebuffer and then use the result as a normal texture?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, antialiasing, multisampling

I'm developing a little gamedev library. One of the elements of this library is a Canvas (offscreen drawing area), which is implemented through an OpenGL framebuffer. So far, everything's been good, I generate a texture, attach it to a framebuffer, render to it, then use the framebuffer's texture as Texture2D.

Now, I'd like to add antialiasing to my library, so I'd like to be able to set multisampling on a Canvas. Now I'm confused because I've found that you need to alter shaders to use multisample textures and so on.

So, what should I do to enable multisampling for my framebuffers so that I minimize changing the rest of the code of the library? I'd like to just use the rendering result as a regular Texture2D if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to make sure that there's no confusion. You can't just create a texture that is x times bigger and then wish that filters will do the magic. Because `GL_LINEAR`, etc. only [averages the four texels closest to the center of the pixel being textured](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml).

To create a multisample texture you'd use [`glTexImage2DMultisample()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2DMultisample.xhtml) (available in core since 3.2). You'd set it up like this.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, tex);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, samples, GL_RGBA8, width, height, false);
```

*It should be self-explanatory as `samples` being the amount of samples in the multisample texture. Also change the `internalformat` as you please.*

To attach the texture to a framebuffer you equally use [`glFramebufferTexture2D()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture2D.xml). But instead of setting the `textarget` as `GL_TEXTURE_2D` you set it to `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE`.

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, tex, 0);
```

*Remember to check the status of your framebuffer.*

In your shader you'll also have to use `sampler2DMS` to be able to access the multisample texture. However note that multisample textures work quite differently compared to regular textures. If you want to read from the texture you'll have to use [`texelFetch()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml).

So if you want to sample from a multisample texture then you can't use [`texture()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml) but would have to utilize [`texelFetch()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml) with something like.

```
uniform int texSamples;
uniform sampler2DMS tex;

vec4 textureMultisample(sampler2DMS sampler, ivec2 coord)
{
    vec4 color = vec4(0.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < texSamples; i++)
        color += texelFetch(sampler, coord, i);

    color /= float(texSamples);

    return color;
}
```

Note that [`texelFetch()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml) doesn't take normalized coordinates, you can circumvent this with something like:

```
vec2 uv = vec2(0.5, 0.5); // normalized coordinates
ivec2 texSize = textureSize(tex, 0);
ivec2 texCoord = ivec2(uv * texSize);
vec4 color = textureMultisample(tex, texCoord);
```

At the end of the day if you want display the crisp anti-aliased result, you'll have to blit it to the screen.

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, src_width, src_height, 0, 0, dst_width, dst_height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
```

If you need a multisample depth buffer then look into [`glRenderbufferStorageMultisample()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glRenderbufferStorageMultisample.xhtml).

Also make sure that `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)`. However today most drivers enable it by default.

Last but not least, here's a few other Stack Overflow/Exchange question related to multisampling that you might find interesting.

- [Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30722236/2470818)
- [`texelFetch()` vs `texture()`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/66475/34057)
- [Multisample Window Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42858872/2470818)

Comment: Thanks for an elaborate answer! So, if I understand correctly, if I want to draw to a multisampled texture and use the result as a regular texture, I first have to Blit that multisampled texture (framebuffer) to a non-multisampled, am I right? Or is there a way around that?

Comment: You can use it *like* a regular texture in a shader if you can live with the `sampler2DMS` and `texelFetch()` / `textureMultisample()`. But other than that, then yes if you want to convert a multisample texture to a regular one, you'd have to blit it between 2 framebuffers.

Comment: Can you explain why [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml) it says that texture() is supported for gsampler2DMS? Documentation error?

Comment: @Vallentin I am using glBlitFramebuffer to resolve MSAA texture and it works fine on Windows, but on Linux the command fails with notorious 1280 error. Turned out that glBlitFramebuffer (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml) requires both framebuffers to have identical number of samples, so looks like this method is technically against the spec. Am I missing something?

Comment: _"You can't just create a texture that is x times bigger and then wish that filters will do the magic"_ — actually you can, but you'll need to use mip mapping filters, and call `glGenerateMipmap()` between rendering into the texture and sampling it. What is actually very different between this supersampling and the typical multisampling is that the latter is faster due to execution of fragment shaders once per fragment rather than per sample (this is not always true, see `glMinSampleShading()`).